# Is it possible to implement Enums in TypeScript that receive parameters like in Java?

Tags: typescript, enums

I am Java programmer for a long time and now I am studying Angular which led me to study TypeScript.

I'm developing something simple to practice and I came across a situation where in the Java world I would create an Enum.

From what I saw TypeScript supports this Enum concept, however, compared to Java, it is quite limited.

To work around the limitations of Enum in TypeScript I thought of using a class that behaves like an enum.

Is the implementation below "okay" according to good practices in the TypeScript world?

Is it possible to implement Enums in TypeScript that receive parameters like in Java? Or is this really only possible through classes?

```
export class MyEnum {

    public static readonly ENUM_VALUE1 = new MyEnum('val1_prop1', 'val1_prop2');
    public static readonly ENUM_VALUE2 = new MyEnum('val2_prop1', 'val2_prop2');
    public static readonly ENUM_VALUE3 = new MyEnum('val3_prop1', 'val3_prop2');

    private readonly _prop1: string;
    private readonly _prop2: string;

    private constructor(prop1: string, prop2: string){
        this._prop1 = prop1;
        this._prop2 = prop2;
    }

    get prop1(): string{
        return this._prop1;
    }

    get prop2(): string{
        return this._prop2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to implement Enums in TypeScript that receive parameters like in Java? Or is this really only possible through classes?

I don't believe so.
There are a few libraries around for this kind of thing though: https://lmfinney.wordpress.com/2017/07/12/ts-enums-bringing-java-style-enums-to-typescript/

But it's really just a more fully-featured version of what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

You could force an enum type with an `any` cast like below. But I think the class solution is better.

```
class MyEnumType {
    constructor(public val1: number, public val2: number) { }
}

enum MyEnum {
    Enum1 = <any>new MyEnumType(1, 2),
    Enum2 = <any>new MyEnumType(3, 4)
}

let enum1 = MyEnum.Enum1;
console.log(enum1 == MyEnum.Enum1); // true
console.log((<MyEnumType><any>enum1).val1); // 1
```